# jssor nested image slider: how to make slider load dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, jssor

Using nested slider load images in condition based

Should i need to hardcode the HTML content  for egg i'm having 3 child  slider
in some cases   some slider will be not having any images in this case i need to hide that child slider and thumbnail as well

I tried to hide the div's by checking the values in java script its not getting hided as well as its taking some superior level css

[link which i used](http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html)

any advice will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code html content, but not necessary, you can populate html content dynamically.

But you'd get html content populated well before you initialize slider(s).

```
//load content and populate html code dynamically
//and then initialize your slider(s) using statement below,
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider(...;
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay jssor i ended up by deleting the Div content which i don't want